# How to bind a key combination to a command?

Tags: lighttable

I have recently run into the following use case in LightTable:

- I want to execute a command (for instance, duplicate a line)
- I press "Ctrl-Space" and a list of commands shows up
- I select the command I need
- I want to repeat this command often, but there is no keybinding for this command
- I go to `user.keymap` where I am supposed to add a line like `[:editor "alt-shift-w" :editor.watch.unwatch]`
- But I have no idea what is the `:editor.watch.unwatch`-like key for the command I have just found. All I know is the displayed name of this command: `Editor: duplicate line`

Is there a way to add this keybinding without digging up the documentation and finding the key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the beginning of a line like this to your *user.keymap*:

```
[:editor "alt-shift-w"
```

and position the keyboard cursor at the end of the line you should be able to type `duplicate line` and the relevant command should be listed in a popup autocomplete menu.

Comment: It worked! What tripped me up is you have to just type `"alt-shift-w"` (or any other key comdination), type a space and start typing the name of the command. If you type the semicolon, however, the popup switches from [nice user-readable names](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/26359914/user-readable.PNG) to [Clojure keys](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/26359914/non-user-readable.PNG).